# Gson: Derserialize a dynamic field

Tags: java, android, json, kotlin, gson

I'm using a very strange api, it's data field type is dynamic.
If error occured, the data field will be a string like this:

```json
{
  "code": 2001,
  "data": "Error!"
}
```

And if success, the data field will be a object:

```json
{
  "code": 2000,
  "data": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "example"
  }
}
```

I'm using the following Kotlin code to de-serialize it:

```kotlin
return Gson().fromJson(data, SimpleModel::class.java)
```

The model definition is down below:

```kotlin
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName

class SimpleModel {
    @SerializedName("code")
    val code = 0

    @SerializedName("data")
    val data: SimpleData = SimpleData()
}

class SimpleData {
    @SerializedName("id")
    val id = ""

    @SerializedName("name")
    val name = ""
}
```

When no error occred, the code above works just fine. However when error occured, exception was thrown:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Excepted BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column x $path.data
```

Is there a way to de-serialize `data` field to an object or just anything and determine it's type by code manually?

Comment: It is nothing strange, it is **very** common. 1) Make your `SimpleModel` class and its data field generic (with `var data: T? = null` in Kotlin if I'm not mistaken). 2) Once the model class becomes generic, `SimpleModel::class.java` won't work anymore because it does not retain the generic type parameterization info, therefore you will need something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33381384/how-to-use-typetoken-generics-with-gson-in-kotlin in order to let Gson know what the actual type parameter of the `SimpleModel` is.

Comment: Thank you so much, I will have a try for that.

Comment: Okay, I got a few more remarks to your specific problems. If the `data` field, when it's a string, always means an error (yeah, it is strange, I missed that in my previous comment), and a success is always an object, then you need to create a `JsonDeserializer` or `TypeAdapterFactory` implementation to detect the type of the object type during deserialization and deserialize that in either a success or an error object, depending. It's more complex than what I suggested above, and probably I'll suggested you a solution in Java later.

Answer (score 2):

Like the previous answer, I am not familiarized with Kotlin, and the following solution is in Java, but as I know it is easy to convert Java to Kotlin using IntelliJ built-in tools.

The success/error objects pair is a classic problem, and you can create your own way to solve it, but let's consider the following classes represent the success and error objects respectively (Java 17, pattern matching on switch enabled then):

```java
abstract sealed class SimpleModel<T>
        permits SimpleModelSuccess, SimpleModelError {

    @SerializedName("code")
    final int code;

    SimpleModel(final int code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

}

final class SimpleModelSuccess<T>
        extends SimpleModel<T> {

    @SerializedName("data")
    final T data;

    private SimpleModelSuccess(final int code, final T data) {
        super(code);
        this.data = data;
    }

}

final class SimpleModelError<T>
        extends SimpleModel<T> {

    @SerializedName("data") // the annotation is helping here!
    final String message;

    private SimpleModelError(final int code, final String message) {
        super(code);
        this.message = message;
    }

}
```

The code above can explain itself. Now the core part that required more work than I thought before by providing you my first comment that appeared incomplete.

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
final class SimpleModelTypeAdapterFactory
        implements TypeAdapterFactory {

    @Getter
    private static final TypeAdapterFactory instance = new SimpleModelTypeAdapterFactory();

    @Override
    @Nullable
    public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(final Gson gson, final TypeToken<T> typeToken) {
        if ( !SimpleModel.class.isAssignableFrom(typeToken.getRawType()) ) {
            return null;
        }
        // let's figure out what the model is parameterized with
        final Type type = typeToken.getType();
        final Type typeParameter;
        if ( type instanceof ParameterizedType parameterizedType ) {
            typeParameter = parameterizedType.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
        } else {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Cannot infer type parameter from " + type);
        }
        // then borrow their respective type adapters for both success and error cases
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        final TypeAdapter<T> successDelegate = (TypeAdapter<T>) gson.getDelegateAdapter(this, TypeToken.getParameterized(SimpleModelSuccess.class, typeParameter));
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        final TypeAdapter<T> errorDelegate = (TypeAdapter<T>) gson.getDelegateAdapter(this, TypeToken.getParameterized(SimpleModelError.class, typeParameter));
        return new TypeAdapter<>() {
            @Override
            public void write(final JsonWriter out, final T value) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
            }

            @Override
            public T read(final JsonReader in) {
                // buffer the JSON tree first
                // note that this solution may be very inefficient under some circumstances
                final JsonObject buffer = Streams.parse(in).getAsJsonObject();
                final JsonElement dataElement = buffer.get("data");
                // is it's data is {...}, the consider it is success (by the way, what is code about?)
                if ( dataElement.isJsonObject() ) {
                    return successDelegate.fromJsonTree(buffer);
                }
                // if it's a primitive, consider it's an error
                if ( dataElement.isJsonPrimitive() ) {
                    return errorDelegate.fromJsonTree(buffer);
                }
                // well we've done our best...
                throw new JsonParseException(String.format("Cannot deduce the model for %s", buffer.getClass()));
            }
        };
    }

}
```

```java
public final class SimpleModelTypeAdapterFactoryTest {

    private static final class SomeJsonProvider
            implements ArgumentsProvider {

        @Override
        public Stream<? extends Arguments> provideArguments(final ExtensionContext context) {
            return Stream.of(
                    Arguments.of(
                            """
                            {
                                "code": 2000,
                                "data": {
                                    "id": 1,
                                    "name": "example"
                                }
                            }
                            """
                    ),
                    Arguments.of(
                            """
                            {
                                "code": 2001,
                                "data": "Error!"
                            }
                            """
                    )
            );
        }

    }

    @AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
    @ToString
    private static final class SimpleData {

        private final String id;
        private final String name;

    }

    private static final Type simpleModelOfSimpleDataType = TypeToken.getParameterized(SimpleModel.class, SimpleData.class)
            .getType();

    @ParameterizedTest
    @ArgumentsSource(SomeJsonProvider.class)
    public void test(final String json) {
        final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .disableHtmlEscaping()
                .disableInnerClassSerialization()
                .registerTypeAdapterFactory(SimpleModelTypeAdapterFactory.getInstance())
                .create();
        final SimpleModel<SimpleData> model = gson.fromJson(json, simpleModelOfSimpleDataType);
        switch ( model ) {
        case SimpleModelSuccess<SimpleData> success -> System.out.println(success.data);
        case SimpleModelError<SimpleData> error -> System.out.println(error.message);
        }
    }

}
```

Here is what it prints to stdout:

> SimpleModelTypeAdapterFactoryTest.SimpleData(id=1, name=example)
> Error!

Well, yeah, this is a "bit" more tricky than it was suggested by my first comment.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to write a custom deserializer, which decides what type to deserialize `data` into, depending on the runtime type of the node, and register that deserializer with your `Gson` instance. Unfortunately i am not familiar with kotlin syntax, so i can only give you pseudo code.

1. Field `data` in `SimpleModel` should be either `Object`, or make the class generic - `SimpleModel<T>`, and the field should be of type `T` as well.
2. Parse the input to gson's node type - `JsonElement`.
3. Get data field

```
JsonElement root = parseResponse();
root.getAsJsonObject().get("data").getAsString();
```

4. Use `getAs...()` methods to check type.
5. Get as string. If success, it's a string and set the string value in `SimpleModel`.
6. If you get exception getting as string, get it as object - `getAsJsonObject()`, parse the object to `SimpleData` and set this new object in `SimpleModel`.

You could use my [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71224888/deserialize-to-generic-member-based-on-value/71225573#71225573) as inspiration. Although it's about object mapper, it does the same thing - decides object type depending on the node type, and follows roughly the same algorithm i described above.

Also [this guide](https://www.baeldung.com/gson-deserialization-guide) has info about how to write yor own deserialzer and registering it.